# Should add and remove actions have the same style?

Tags: buttons, interface

I have a prototype with the following icons. Add button and remove button are different. Do you think that this is the best approach? Or would you use the same style for the buttons. 
Image attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isn't an exact right or wrong answer, but being consistent is always better. There are cases when you want to emphasize a certain action more than others, in which case inconsistency may be what you want.

In this case, the `remove` action is more heavily weighted, so unless you want to encourage users to do that, I'd suggest making the icons the same style.

Comment: On the other hand the convention nowadays is to differentiate when there is two distinct actions, red/green for phone calls, ok/cancel, approve/reject, save/cancel... So in this case I think it might be better to be consistent with the convention.

Answer (score 3):

If the icons do different things, then they should look different, and look different at a glance (especially if one is Remove).

I like yours, with one filled in and the other open. They look similar enough to live on the same page, but distinct enough to tell them apart easily.